# How to fix error in joining two tables together

Tags: sql

This is my first time ever working with sql and my first task is joining two tables together. I saw a similar example of how its done which worked and tried it for this example but it did not work. I am not sure why I am getting an error

```
SELECT os.city_id
        ,os.park_id AS slide_id
from om_slide AS os
where os.city_id = 12
LEFT JOIN ga_park gt ON (os.park_id=gt.park_id)
```

I know it works up to the where os.city_id = 12. that gives me a result. Just my left statement is not working and I do not know why

Comment: `from om_slide AS os

LEFT JOIN ga_park gt ON (os.park_id=gt.park_id) where os.city_id = 12`

Comment: Why are you joining at all here? I can't see where you've selected anything from the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your preferences may differ but I find [explicit joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) easier to read. Your `LEFT JOIN` may appear as though it's not working because you aren't selecting anything from that table. Subject to my comment to that effect on the question I'd go with something like:

```
SELECT
    os.city_id, os.park_id AS slide_id, gt.*
FROM
    om_slide AS os
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ga_park AS gt
ON
    os.park_id=gt.park_id
WHERE
    os.city_id = 12
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want info from the `om_slide` table for a given `city_id`, the following should work.

```
SELECT os.city_id
        , os.park_id AS slide_id
FROM om_slide AS os
WHERE os.city_id = 12
```

If you want additional info from the `ga_park` table also, for a given `city_id`, then use the following.

```
SELECT os.city_id
        , os.park_id AS slide_id
        , gt.park_name -- or whatever additional field(s) you want from ga_park
FROM om_slide AS os LEFT JOIN ga_park AS gt ON os.park_id = gt.park_id
WHERE os.city_id = 12
```

Comment: Isn't the `JOIN` still superfluous here? What is it selecting?

Comment: Guessing that OP's eventual goal is to get additional data from the `ga_park` table. If it's just the `park_id` for a given `city_id`, then you are right, there is no need to join `om_side` and `ga_park` tables, OP could just query the `om_slide` table.